# How to use where in partition by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following code

```
select 
     *,
     count(*) over (partition by name where message is not Null) as "mes_count"
from messages
```

I want to get the table with the column `mes_count` that would be the same on the rows with the same name (and I don't want to count messages with null values). So how should I rewrite the code?

Answer (score 2):

Postgres supports `filter` so you can use that:

```
select m.*,
       count(*) filter (where messaage is not null) over (partition by name) as mes_count
from messages;
```

But `count(*)` does this automatically, so you might as well use:

```
select m.*,
       count(messaage) over (partition by name) as mes_count
from messages;
```

Answer (score -1):

The condition must be set in the count, not the partition clause.

```
-- Auxiliary data for testing purposes
with messages (name, message) as (
    select 'n1', 1 union all
    select 'n1', 2 union all
    select 'n3', null)
-- Actual query
SELECT
    m.*,
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN message IS NOT NULL THEN
                1
        END
    ) OVER(
        PARTITION BY name
    ) AS mes_count
FROM
    messages m;
```

Output:

```
name, message, mes_count
------------------------
n1           1         2
n1           2         2
n3        null         0
```

DB Fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=98bf9b9a5de05fc3e55e1ec10790aa82